# Cannot run Warble (NoMethodError: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class)

Tags: ruby, jruby, warbler

I'm new to Jruby and fairly new to Ruby as well.

I was trying to compile to a jar with Warbler, but any Warbler command I run gives the same response:

````
NoMethodError: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/task.rb:45:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/application.rb:27:in `new'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/application.rb:27:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/application.rb:79:in `run'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/lib/warbler/application.rb:74:in `run'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/warbler-2.0.5/bin/warble:11:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/warble:32:in `load'
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/warble:32:in `<main>'```
````

I tried running Warbler and expected it to compile to jar (or work when running a help command)

Comment: sorry for the ` spam, it was using `s in the error and I wasn't sure how to format it properly

Comment: Seems like `exists?` is removed in ruby 3.2, https://github.com/beefproject/beef/issues/2739

try singular, i.e. `exist?`

Comment: @BikiMaharjan there's no `exists?` in my code, so I think it's a Warbler thing. Thank you

Comment: Oh, Then try upgrading Warbler gem.